# Simple OWL statements where a Student can be a BachelorStudent, MasterStudent or PhDStudent

Tags: rdf, owl, rdfs

I am currently preparing for an exam, and I am having some trouble writing some simple OWL statements:

> a. A Student is either a BachelorStudent, MasterStudent or PhDStudent.

Is this as easy as just making bachelor, master and phd a subclass of Student? I mean, how do you force a Student to be a member of one of these classes?

Also this:

> b. No Student is more than one of these: BachelorStudent, MasterStudent and PhDStudent.

How can you set a max cardinality when there is no property? Or do you make the 3 disjoint?

Here are some more if anybody is willing to give som input on how they are solveable:

> c. A Student takes at least one Course.
>
> d. A Course is either a BachelorCourse, MasterCourse or PhDCourse.
>
> e. A BachelorStudent takes only BachelorCourses.
>
> f. The MasterThesis is a MasterCourse.
>
> g. A MasterStudent takes at least five Courses

Comment: well, you should have had some lectures then, right? given that you're talking about classes, I'd simply use disjoint union as introduced in OWL 2 in combination with an equivalence axiom.

Comment: that you're not able to solve the others looks strange to me? what did you learn in the lecture? in Manchester OWLSyntax it would be something like c) `Student SubClassOf takes some Course` ... e) `BachelorStudent SubClassOf takes only BachelorCourses` - the rest is up to you, it's almost trivial

Comment: I am using TURTLE syntax. I can partly write some of the statements, but I am having issues FORCING an individual (Student) to be a member of one of the classes. Like, I can make the three subclasses of Student, but then again you can be member of the Student class and no one else

Comment: Why can't you simply say `Student EquivalentTo BachelorStudent or MasterStudent or PhDStudent`?

Comment: By the way, I'd never use Turtle syntax for OWL, especially when you have to model OWL specific constructs like union, intersection, existential restriction, etc. - those constructs are mapped to multiple RDF triples, thus, it's much more verbose than e.g. Manchester OWL syntax or OWL Functional Syntax.

Comment: The exam is in 2 days, so I think ill have to stick with TURTLe since that is what I know. Also, I did all of the statements. Would be extremely helpful if you could take a look: https://imgur.com/a/CDmL2sq